# Need Help using string with brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, brackets

I am a total newb to python. I pieced together a code that works great except when I have brackets in the string for the find_str variable. I tried using double brackets but it doesn't work either.

The goal is to replace all text in a list of CSV's that contain `_(FAIL)_` with `SUCCESS`.

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import re


filenames = sorted(glob.glob('*.csv'))
filenames = filenames
for f2 in filenames:

    csv_name=f2

    # open your csv and read as a text string
    with open(csv_name, 'r') as f:
        my_csv_text = f.read()

    find_str = "_(FAIL)_"
    replace_str = "SUCCESS"


    # substitute
    new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)


    # open new file and save
    new_csv_path = csv_name 
    with open(new_csv_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_csv_str)
```

Comment: `find_str = "_\(FAIL\)_"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you need to escape the brackets

Try:

```
find_str = "_\(FAIL\)_"
replace_str = "SUCCESS"

# substitute
new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a regular expression and `re.sub()` for this, `str.replace()` will do the job:

```
find_str = "_(FAIL)_"
replace_str = "SUCCESS"

my_csv_text = 'We go through life and _(FAIL)_ and _(FAIL)_ and _(FAIL)_'

new_csv_str = my_csv_text.replace(find_str, replace_str)

print(new_csv_str)
```

Gives:

```
We go through life and SUCCESS and SUCCESS and SUCCESS
```